# How to access an attribute of different class in python

Tags: python, class, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to form a Binary Search Tree and print it. I am getting the following error:

```
self.root.left.printtree() AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'printtree'
```

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

class Binarysearchtree():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.root=Node(data)
        
    def insert(self,data):
        if self.root.data>data:
            if self.root.left==None:
                self.root.left=Node(data)
            else:
                self.root.left.insert(data)
        elif self.root.data<data:
            if self.root.right==None:
                self.root.right=Node(data)
            else:
                self.root.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.root.data=data
        
    def printtree(self):
        if self.root.left:
            self.root.left.printtree()
        print(self.root.data)
        if self.root.right:
            self.root.right.printtree()
           
a=Binarysearchtree(23)
a.insert(20)
a.insert(24)
a.printtree()
```

Comment: Indenting is important in Python. The code above has various levels of indenting, which makes it hard to understand what you are trying to do. You should edit the question and make sure the indenting really matches what you are doing.

Comment: You have defined the `printtree` method on the tree and not on the nodes... and you are calling it on the nodes. Either also define it on the nodes or make it take a node as argument.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def print_tree(self):
        print(self.data)
        if self.left:
            self.left.print_tree()
        if self.right:
            self.right.print_tree()

class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.root = Node(data)

    def insert(self,data):
        if self.root.data > data:
            if self.root.left is None:
                self.root.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.root.left.insert(data)
        elif self.root.data < data:
            if self.root.right is None:
                self.root.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.root.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.root.data = data

    def print_tree(self):
        self.root.print_tree()


a = BinarySearchTree(23)

a.insert(20)
a.insert(24)

a.print_tree()
```

you need to put your `print_tree` function in the `Node` class. You also have to change your `print_tree` function `BinarySearchTree` and you have to use the `print_tree` function of `Node`

Don't forget to respect respect the `snake case` convention

Comment: This will have the same issue with `insert()` as soon as you try to insert more items. (Also, you changed the order of printing from the original).

Comment: Indeed, I didn't really checked his `insert()` function. You're right it deosn't work pretty well

Comment: So it is better to use same class for both node and tree? I am new to classes in python

Comment: @vinoths, yes, it is more convenient to put these methods on the Node class and use the Tree class as a wrapper to keep track of the root. `insert()` on the tree would then look something like: `def insert(self,data):  self.root.insert(data)`. The real logic would be on the Node.

Comment: Thanks Mark I will work on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create BST like this

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

def createNode(root_node, data):
    while(root_node != None):
        if data < root_node.data:
            if root_node.left == None:
                root_node.left = Node(data)
                break
            else:
                root_node = root_node.left
        else:
            if root_node.right == None:
                root_node.right = Node(data)
                break
            else:
                root_node = root_node.right


#In order Traversal
def inOrderTravel(r):
    if r == None:
        return
    inOrderTravel(r.left)
    print(r.data)
    inOrderTravel(r.right)


class Binarysearchtree:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.root = Node(data)
        
    def insert(self,data):
        if data < self.root.data:
            ref_root = self.root
            createNode(ref_root, data)  
        else:
            ref_root = self.root
            createNode(ref_root, data)
        return self.root
        


a = Binarysearchtree(23)
r = a.insert(20)
r = a.insert(24)
r = a.insert(25)
r = a.insert(0)
inOrderTravel(r)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).